# Xamarin Forms Android Renderer crash

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using a custom renderer and i want to add some additional view. So i used `Platform.CreateRenderer(view)` to render the subview. This works great on iOS but on Android I just get this Exception:

`Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x2`

I have no idea what kind of resource is missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the view that you are trying to create. Does it reference any resource that you might have forgot to add to your project?

Comment: The View is also shown as content of another page where it is working. I checked it again but couldn't find missing things

Comment: The Problem seem to be the subview. You are right. But I dont know why. It is a `ContentView` containing a `StackLayout` with a `ListView` and a `Label`. When I remove the `ListView` everythings working. But even with a empty `<ListView/>` Tag it crashes

Comment: Without some more code it's hard to say what the cause could be

Comment: `<ContentView><ListView/></ContentView>` this also crashes.

Comment: May I ask why you are creating renderers dynamically?

Comment: Because I want to add an additional view from xamarin forms. I do not see an other option the put a flyout to a masterdetailpage(split)